# SonarQube security hotspot issue for regex

Tags: javascript, regex, sonarqube

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbUot.png)This is the code that is throwing security hotspot issue on scanning sonarQube

```
rootUri: /.*\/$/.test(sDataSource.uri) ? sDataSource.uri : sDataSource.uri + "/
```

How to resolve this regex issue for this uri

I am getting this security issue while running sonarqube for javascript code.

Comment: And what is full message of this issue from sonarqube?

Comment: I don't know about SonarQube, but `.*\/$` seems unnecessary. Just check whether the last character is `/` or not: `sDataSource.uri.at(-1) === '/'`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use [`String#endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith): `sDataSource.uri.endsWith('/')`.

Comment: You need to provide the error message, or we likely won’t be able to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @InSync I have attached error screenshot

Comment: @brads3290  I have attached error screenshot

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/error/textual content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste them here as text. Also, just remove the regex altogether and use one of the two solutions I gave above.